# integer 'K' will not count correctly within for loop. How do I fix this?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making a DFA for a class project. I have the code mostly written and everything seems correct but my integer, K, always returns a value of 0. What am I doing wrong with this method?

```
public static void give(char[] states, String testString)
{
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < testString.toCharArray().length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("i is: " + i);
        System.out.println("k is: " + k);
        System.out.println("State is: " + states[k] + "\n");
        
        if(states[k] == 'a' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            k = 0;//keeps state at 'a'
        }
        if(states[k] == 'a' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            k++;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(states[k] == 'b' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            k++;
        }
        if(states[k] == 'b' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            k = 0;//resets state to 'a'
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(states[k] == 'c' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            k++;
        }
        if(states[k] == 'c' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            k = 0;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(states[k] == 'd' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            k = 0;
        }
        if(states[k] == 'd' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            k++;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        if(states[k] == 'e' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            System.out.println(states[k]);
        }
        if(states[k] == 'e' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            System.out.println(states[k]);
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```

Basically this method takes my array of states and a String of integers (ex: "1001"). It should take each member of the string as a character and use it as the next input along with the state. So, if the state is 'a' and the input is '1' the state should change to 'b', but that requires my integer K to increment so that states[k] goes to states[k+1] and so on. K keeps returning as 0 and I am not sure why. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Have you stepped through your program with the debugger?

Comment: I have not done that yet. It's not something I think about because it isn't taught at my school. It's just kinda "here ya go good luck" lol. I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You go to the next state, before the loop (which goes through the string) makes a turn, you try to update the state multiple times in a single loop round. So the solution is to use else if instead of if. Like this:

```
public static void give(char[] states, String testString)
    {
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < testString.toCharArray().length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("i is: " + i);
        System.out.println("k is: " + k);
        System.out.println("State is: " + states[k] + "\n");
        
        if(states[k] == 'a' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            k = 0;//keeps state at 'a'
        }
        else if(states[k] == 'a' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            k++;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        else if(states[k] == 'b' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            k++;
        }
        else if(states[k] == 'b' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            k = 0;//resets state to 'a'
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        else if(states[k] == 'c' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            k++;
        }
       else if(states[k] == 'c' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            k = 0;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        else if(states[k] == 'd' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            k = 0;
        }
        else if(states[k] == 'd' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            k++;
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        else if(states[k] == 'e' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '0')
        {
            System.out.println(states[k]);
        }
        else if(states[k] == 'e' && testString.toCharArray()[i] == '1')
        {
            System.out.println(states[k]);
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
```